# How do I call my gesture recognise function

Tags: ios, swift

This is my function that when someone taps, I want the code to be executed I added it programmatically.

```
    func reload(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
        let skView = self.view!
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

I'm trying to call it, but no way works that I have tried, my latest attempt is this but I keep getting the error... "use of unresolved identifier 'reload'" in the lines where I call the reload function in the if statement. reload(gestureRecognizer: nil)

```
    if score[0] >= 10 {
        pauseGame()

        let textLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica")
        textLabel.fontSize = 30
        textLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
        textLabel.position = CGPoint(x:  20, y: 20)
        textLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center
        textLabel.text = "HELLO"
        addChild(textLabel)

        reload(gestureRecognizer: nil)

    }
    else if
        score [1] >= 10 {
        pauseGame()
        sleep(5)

        let textLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "ChalkboardSE-Bold")
        textLabel.fontSize = 30
        textLabel.fontColor = SKColor.white
        textLabel.position = CGPoint(x:  20, y: 20)
        textLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center
        textLabel.text = "HELLO"
        addChild(textLabel)

        reload(gestureRecogniser: nil)

    }
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, Thank you!

Comment: Is that all in the same class?

Comment: You have many, many problems here!  (1) you should use storyboard, do not make labels/etc on the fly.  Use storyboard.  (2) Simply HIDE/unhide them as needed.  (3) never, ever, ever use "sleep". in games use a timer. (4) "unresolved identifier" just means you have the function in the wrong class somewhere.

Comment: How do I know what class to put it in? And what should I use instead of sleep and why shouldn't I use it?

Comment: Reposting is not acceptable here.

Answer (score 0):

Search for all the places you use ‘reload’ in your code. One of them most likely is using the wrong class / target.

Usages of ‘reload’ you have shown above shouldn’t have any problem. I suspect that there is something else using reload that you haven’t disclosed yet.

Comment: How do I know what class to put the code in?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that function to be called every time the user taps on your view, then in the storyboard, drag a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on top of the view. Then, connect the recognizer to the 'reload' function in your code as an action function. Be sure to add `@IBAction` to the function:

```
@IBAction func reload(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
    let skView = self.view!
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

EDIT: If you don't want this function to be executed every time, then you could just put your `if` statement in the beginning of the functon:

```
@IBAction func reload(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {
    if (score >= 10) {
        return
    }
    let skView = self.view!
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Comment: I only wanti t after my score reaches ten, not any time. Like how it shows in my if statements, could you show me how to do that please?

Comment: You could easliy just put your if statement right at the beginning of your reload function. Then, if your score reaches ten, you immediately return from the function.